# How can i render a component by the page I'm on?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-router-dom

I'd like to know how can I do not display Navbar/Footer when I'm on Login Page or Register Page.

This is the Register Page (Which in my case don't need a Navbar/footer)

[Register.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAGqS.jpg)

But, in others pages, i'd like to keep these.

[Home, About etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3Swk.png)

Here's my code:

```
import "./App.css";

import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home/Home";
import About from "./pages/About/About";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Login from "./pages/Login/Login";
import Register from "./pages/Register/Register";

const url = "http://localhost:3000/"

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar /> {/* If actual page is Login/Register, do not display*/}
        <div className="container">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />

          </Routes>
        </div>
      <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You forgot to post the code mate

Comment: Here u go, sorry =p

Comment: Don't post code as images...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use `conditional rendering`.

Say you have a `/login`, a `/register` and a `/home` route. You only want to render the `<NavBar />` component on `/home` or on routes other than `/login` and `/register`.

You will need to use a hook called `useLocation` exported from `react-router-dom`.

```
const RoutesContainer = props => {
  const path = useLocation().pathname
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {["/login", "/register"].includes(path) ? null : <NavBar />}
      <Route path="/home" component={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/login" component={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/register" component={<Register />} />
    </Fragment>        
  )
}

const App = props => (
  <Router>
    <RoutesContainer />
  </Router>
)
```

The reason `RoutesContainer` is a separate component is because `react-router-dom` will not allow you to use the `useLocation` hook outside of a `BrowserRouter` component.

EDIT: This is a solution for `react-router-dom` < v6. You may have to modify `component` to `element`.

Comment: Ok, but will i keep using BrowserRouter, Routes and Route? The code above i use on App.js?